# SQL ORACLE converting table to the html code

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on oracle and taking report from database Oracle.

```
SELECT OPERATION, OBJECT_TYPE, CPU_COST, IO_COST FROM SYS.V_$SQL_PLAN;
```

I want to send this report with html formate in mail body to the Database Admin.
Is there any way to do this in pl-sql in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible you need:

a) PL/SQL procedure to create the body html out of the SQL

b) PL/SQL procedure to send the body html in an html email to the admin

For a) here you can write a custom procedure which creates the html out of the sql cursor

```
for cur in (select * from query) loop
    html := html || '<tr>';
    html := html || '<td>';
    html := html || cur.col1;
    html := html || '</td>';
    html := html || '<td>';
    html := html || cur.col2;
    html := html || '</td>';
    ...
    html := html || '<td>';
    html := html || cur.coln;
    html := html || '</td>';
    html := html || '</tr>';
```

or search/write some generic code like https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/create-html-table-from-oracle-table-in-plsql/

For b) Use UTL_SMTP

Comment: Thank you Thomas, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use all steps mentioned in attached screenshot, in case of any problem let me know to help you.

Here instead of col 1 you can define col 2, col 3 .... And so on, with one open td and one close td in similar way.

Make sure data count is not more then 10000. Else during browser load it will hang.